# Bigquery extracting sequences from timeseries data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, time-series

I have a timeseries in BQ, with additional data, and based on some of the data I want to extract sequences from the timeseries for further processing.

The following demonstrates the source table:

```
with dataset as (
 select
    timestamp('2023-01-25 00:00:00') as last_seen, 1 as vehicle_id, 1 as mode, 0 as activity 
    union all select timestamp('2023-01-25 00:00:02'), 1, 1, 0
    union all select timestamp('2023-01-25 00:00:04'), 1, 1, 0
    union all select timestamp('2023-01-25 00:00:00'), 2, 1, 0
    union all select timestamp('2023-01-25 00:00:02'), 2, 1, 0
    union all select timestamp('2023-01-25 00:00:04'), 2, 1, 0
    union all select timestamp('2023-01-25 00:00:06'), 1, 2, 1
    union all select timestamp('2023-01-25 00:00:08'), 1, 2, 1
    union all select timestamp('2023-01-25 00:00:10'), 1, 2, 1
    union all select timestamp('2023-01-25 00:00:12'), 1, 1, 0
    union all select timestamp('2023-01-25 00:00:14'), 1, 1, 0
    union all select timestamp('2023-01-25 00:00:16'), 1, 1, 0
    union all select timestamp('2023-01-25 00:00:12'), 2, 1, 1
    union all select timestamp('2023-01-25 00:00:14'), 2, 1, 1
    union all select timestamp('2023-01-25 00:00:17'), 2, 1, 1
)
```

What I want is to have a result that for every time the mode and/or activity changes for each vehicle_id which includes the start and end timestamps. Eg like this:

| vehicle_id | mode | activity | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 2023-01-25 00:00:00 | 2023-01-25 00:00:04 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2023-01-25 00:00:06 | 2023-01-25 00:00:10 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 2023-01-25 00:00:12 | 2023-01-25 00:00:16 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 2023-01-25 00:00:00 | 2023-01-25 00:00:04 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2023-01-25 00:00:12 | 2023-01-25 00:00:17 |

I have tried:

```
select * from dataset where true
qualify ifnull(mode != lag(mode) over win or activity != lag(activity) over win or mode != lead(mode) over win or activity != lead(activity) over win, true)
window win as (partition by vehicle_id order by last_seen)
```

But that gives start and end on separate rows, so it feels like a dead end as it might cause issues if a sequence does not have an end.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider below.

```sql
SELECT vehicle_id, 
       ANY_VALUE(mode) mode, ANY_VALUE(activity) activity,
       MIN(last_seen) AS start, MAX(last_seen) AS `end`
  FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNTIF(flag) OVER w1 AS part FROM (
      SELECT *, mode <> LAG(mode) OVER w0 OR activity <> LAG(activity) OVER w0 AS flag
        FROM dataset
      WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY vehicle_id ORDER BY last_seen)
    ) WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY vehicle_id ORDER BY last_seen)
  ) GROUP BY vehicle_id, part;
```

**Query results**

[image]